# Is the an implementation of java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch which can handle incrementing the initial count upward?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I need a java.lang.Thread to wait for an unpredictable number of predecessor threads to complete as a "choke point" before releasing the spawning of another batch of threads.  CountDownLatch seems like it would work if there was a method for countUp as well as countDown.

Is there a implementation like this, or do I need to implement a semaphore singularity myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`java.util.concurrent.Phaser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html)

> A reusable synchronization barrier, similar in functionality to CyclicBarrier and CountDownLatch but supporting more flexible usage.
>
> Unlike the case for other barriers, the number of parties registered to synchronize on a phaser may vary over time. Tasks may be registered at any time . . . and optionally deregistered upon any arrival

Comment: Very interesting.  I'll be wrapping my head around this to see if it will work.